# pl/sql code adding two rows

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm new to pl/sql and in oracle forms in particular.

This is my criteria ( store_A's (value) & store_B's(value) difference is more than 4000 then fire the trigger)

for example: store_A = 500 and store_B = 5000 then call the trigger ( the difference can't be more than 4000)

Please help me modify this code:

```
if :book_daily_stats.store_A > :book_daily_stats.store_B and :book_daily_stats.store_A < 4000
 then
  al_id:= Find_Alert ('Store_Caution')
  al_button:= Show_Alert(al_id)

  if al_button = Alert_Button1
    then
      Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;

  End if;
End;
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Your second paragraph begins by saying the criteria is store_A > 4000; the example immediately following it doesn't fit that criteria nor does it fit the parenthetical comment of no more than 4k difference because the difference is 4500.

Comment: Sorry about that, disregard this ( if store_A > 4000 then call the trigger) ---

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't (normally) "call" a trigger - a trigger gets fired when its triggering condition is met.

For example, you might have a `when-validate-item` trigger on a form item. In that trigger's code you can have something like:

```
if :book_daily_stats.store_A > :book_daily_stats.store_B
  and :book_daily_stats.store_A < 4000 then
    call_message (' Store_B''s value exceeded daily limits');
end if;
```

This `when-validate-item` trigger will get fired whenever the item it is attached to needs to be validated - e.g. when a user types a value into the item and then tries to navigate to another item (e.g. by clicking on another item, or pressing Tab).

Comment: The problem with that code is if Store_B's input value is more than 4k, it fires the trigger. What I'm trying to achieve is that, if the difference of Store_A and Store_B's input are more than 4k then the trigger gets fired.

Comment: That's not how triggers work in Forms. You can't put conditions on them. Instead, just put IF statements inside the trigger to do stuff if the condition is true.